# displaing center of image if the image is longer than the div size

Tags: html, css

I have a div like this :

[image]

The height of image part of the div is 216px . What I want to do is if the image's height is bigger than 216px then the center of img will be shown .So for example the center of that picture will be shown like this:

[image: -5-28-2016-9-59-20-am-jpg]

How could I do so?

THanks

Comment: I suggest as "set as background-size and set value as center"

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with code you already have? Btw you can set it as background and then set background-size and position how you need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your solution..

```html
<div style="background-image:url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/IvPWw.jpg'); height:216px; width:300px; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:0 50%;">
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
background:url("image/path") no-repeat center center;
```

Working demo : http://codepen.io/sandip_rb/pen/YWzGBg?editors=1100#anon-login